# Table data is not going onto report correctly

Tags: ms-access, datatable, report

I have multiple forms (select yes to an option takes you to another form to sign/initial, if you select no, takes you to a different form to sign initial). The data from my first form goes to the first record, but then the data from the second form goes To the second record within the table (and so on). I want all the data to go into this single table, and then into a single report.

Now, when the table is connected to a report to spit out, the only data showing up on the report is the data from the initial form (first record), and not the other information that is flowing to the table in say records 2-5.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jy5z.png)

Comment: Either the table isn't updated as you expect, or the report has a filter that rules out the not seen records.

Comment: Please show the problem rather than tell :)

Comment: I tried adding the image above of how my table is showing up. Basically, for each form, my data goes into a different record, but I want to be able to pull all data from the table into my report and it’s only taking from record 1.

Comment: Additional discovery - when the data in the table goes to the different records, the data then is put onto a new report each time. Now when I view the report in form view, I see multiple reports (the same one), but each report only has one piece of data in it.